# How to manually convert between Latin-5 and Unicode code points?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, dart, decode, iso-8859-1

I have socket connection and I can get data from my socket. The data encoded as Latin-5.

**Example:** // will get data from socket like:

```
_xCustomerName = “879255:_:NÝYAZÝ TOROS”;
_xCustomerName.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'Ý'), 'İ');
```

An seems it doesnt replace the 'Ý' to ‘İ’.

How to manually convert between Latin-5 and Unicode code points?

Answer (score 2):

The Latin-5 characters are specified, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5#Codepage_layout). That looks like Cyrillic to me, so what you need is probably codepage 1254 [*Windows* Latin-5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195056.aspx) or [ISO-8859-9/Latin-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9). They both have Turkish characters with capital dotted I at position 0xDD. The six-character change you mention in your follow-up post matches Latin-9.

From the character table, you can build a translation table with one character per byte in the 0..255 range:

```
import "dart:typed_data";
// The Unicode characters of ISO-8859-9.
const _latin9Table = 
  "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f"
  "\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f"
  " !\"#\$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_"
  "`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f"
  "\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f"
  "\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f"
  "\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf"
  "\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf"
  "\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf"
  "\u011e\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\u0130\u015e\xdf"
  "\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef"
  "\u011f\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\u0131\u015f\xff";
String decodeLatin9(List<int> bytes) {
  Uint16List charCodes = new Uint16List(bytes.length);
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    charCodes[i] = _latin9Table.codeUnitAt(bytes[i]);
  }
  return String.fromCharCodes(charCodes);
}
```

That allows decoding of Latin-9. If you want to combine it into that `dart:convert` framework, you may need to create a `Converter` around that, or even an `Encoding`. Sadly, the `package:convert` doesn't have an easy way to create a code-page convereter. I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

I know the differences Latin-5 (Turkish) character codes.
With simple switch statements I can turn “879255:*:NÝYAZÝ TOROS” to “879255:*:NİYAZİ TOROS”. I wish I had a better solution (some sort of Dart plugin) but this is best I came so far.

```
_xCustomerName.runes.forEach((int rune) {
        var character = new String.fromCharCode(rune);
        switch (character) {
          case 'Ð':
            character = 'Ğ';
            break;
          case 'Ý':
            character = 'İ';
            break;
          case 'Þ':
            character = 'Ş';
            break;
          case 'ð':
            character = 'ğ';
            break;
          case 'ý':
            character = 'ı';
            break;
          case 'þ':
            character = 'ş';
            break;
        }
        _xCustomerNameTurkish = _xCustomerNameTurkish + character;
      });
      print(_xCustomerNameTurkish);
```